# How to customize stripe subscription payment description field

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using stripe as payment gateway for user subscription, I want to add custom description for each subscription, I checked stripe API manual to set description for payment but did not find out for subscription payment ie if payment mode is 'payment' then we can set description by payment intent field parameter
$stripe_session_arr['payment_intent_data']  = ['description'=>'test'];
But not sure how to do same thing for subscription entry, anyone can help me?
[image]

Comment: I highly recommend reaching out to their support on https://support.stripe.com/. I have done that several times even with technical questions and they respond with good answers 24/7.

Comment: thanks, I contact to stripe support, they said such type of feature not provided by API, we can do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

I contact to stripe support team, such type of feature for subscription mode not provided by API.